# Цвет header в searchController

Tags: ios, search, color

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить цвет header или что это такое в поиске? Скрин прилагается. Хотелось бы избавиться от белого цвета над панелью поиска

[image: Цвет]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это status bar с белым текстом поэтому его не видно.
Я делал цвет бара такой же как и меню поиска

```
#pragma mark - TuningStatusBar
- (void)tuningStatusBar {
    UIView *statusBarView =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SelfViewWidth, 22)];
    statusBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.21 green:0.81 blue:0.79 alpha:1];
    [self.view addSubview:statusBarView];
}
```

и этот метод добавить в viewDidLoad